# append output of each iteration of a loop to the same in bash

Tags: bash, loops, wc, vcf-variant-call-format

I have 44 files (2 for each chromosome) divided in two types: .vcf and .filtered.vcf. 
I would like to make a `wc -l`  for each of them in a loop and append the output always to the same file. However, I would like to have 3 columns in this file: chr[1-22], `wc -l` of .vcf and `wc -l` of .filtered.vcf.

I've been trying to do independent `wc -l` for each file and paste together columnwise the 2 outputs for each of the chromosomes, but this is obviously not very efficient, because I'm generating a lot of unnecessary files. I'm trying this code for the 22 pairs of files:

```
wc -l file1.vcf | cut -f 1 > out1.vcf
wc -l file1.filtered.vcf | cut -f 1 > out1.filtered.vcf
paste -d "\t" out1.vcf out1.filtered.vcf
```

I would like to have just one output file containing three columns:

```
Chromosome    VCFCount    FilteredVCFCount
chr1          out1        out1.filtered
chr2          out2        out2.filtered
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: What is `chr[1-22]` ?

Comment: Please post your code, the example output you expect and what you currently get instead.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just want a column with the names of the chromosomes: chr1, chr2, chr3...chr22!

Comment: So the files are chr1.vcf , chr1.filtered.vcf etc. ?

Comment: yes, that's it! I've updated my question... sorry if I'm not really informative :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf "%s\n" *.filtered.vcf |
cut -d. -f1 |
sort |
xargs -n1 sh -c 'printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$1" "$(wc -l <"${1}.vcf")" "$(wc -l <"${1}.filtered.vcf")"' --
```

1. Output newline separated list of files in the directory
2. Remove the extension with cut (probably something along `xargs -i basename {} .filtered.vcf` would be safer)
3. Sort it (for nice sorted output!) (probably something along `sort -tr -k2 -n` would sort numerically and would be even better).
4. `xargs -n1` For each one file execute the script `sh -c`

   1. `printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n"` - output with custom format string ...
   2. `"$1"` - the filename and...
   3. `"(wc -l <"${1}.vcf")"` - the count the lines in .vcf file and...
   4. `"$(wc -l <"${1}.filtered.vcf")"` - the count of the lines in the .filtered.vcf

Example:

```
> touch chr{1..3}{,.filtered}.vcf 
> echo > chr1.filtered.vcf ; echo  > chr2.vcf ; 
>     printf "%s\n" *.filtered.vcf |
>    cut -d. -f1 |
>    sort |
>    xargs -n1 sh -c 'printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$1" "$(wc -l <"${1}.filtered.vcf")" "$(wc -l <"${1}.vcf")"' -- 
chr1    0   1
chr2    1   0
chr3    0   0
```

To have nice looking table with headers, use `column`:

```
> .... | column -N Chromosome,VCFCount,FilteredVCFCount -t -o '    '
Chromosome    VCFCount    FilteredVCFCount
chr1          0           1
chr2          1           0
chr3          0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.

```
for chr in chr*.vcf; do
    base=${chr%.vcf}
    awk -v base="$base" 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"
            # Remove this to not have this pesky header line
            print "Chromosome", "VCFCount", "FilteredVCFCount"
            }
        FNR==1 && n { p=n }
        { n=FNR }
        END { print base, p, n }' "$chr" "$base.filtered.vcf"
done >counts.txt
```

The very simple Awk script just collects the highest line number for each file (so we basically reimplement `wc -l`) and prints the collected numbers in the desired format.  `FNR` is the line number in the current input file; we simply save this, and copy the value to `p` to keep the saved value from the previous file in a separate variable when we switch to a new file (starting over at line number 1).

The shell parameter substitution `${variable%pattern}` retrieves the value of `variable` with any suffix match on `pattern` removed. (There is also `${variable#pattern}` to remove a prefix, and Bash has `##` and `%%` to trim the longest pattern match instead of the shortest.)

If efficiency is important, you could probably refactor all of the script into a single Awk script, but this way, all the pieces are simple and hopefully understandable.